# gojs graphics that are dragged from the palette, and which are not immediately visible on the wire

Tags: javascript, gojs

According to the official example https://gojs.net/latest/samples/draggableLink.html, the `nodeStyle` of the example https://gojs.net/latest/samples/roundedGroups.html is used.

### However, there is a problem:

When dragging a graph from the palette to the diagram, you can find that both `nodeDataArray` and `linkDataArray` have new records, but the connection cannot be displayed immediately, and you must refresh the page to do so.

When comparing the code to the example on the official website, I think the problem lies in the `nodeTemplate`, because my code differs from the key code of the example https://gojs.net/latest/samples/draggableLink.html only in the `nodeTemplate` but I still cannot figure out how to fix it for my specific case.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue or have any insight on how to debug it? *(see code below for reference)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="myDiagramDiv" style="width:1920px;height:1080px;">
</div>
<script th:src="@{/nengli/js/go-debug.js?version=2.3.13}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/nengli/js/Figures.js?version=2.3.13}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/nengli/js/RoundedRectangles.js?version=2.3.13}"></script>
<script th:inline="javascript">
        $(function () {
        init();
    });
</script>
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $('#myPaletteDiv').width($('#myPaletteDiv').width())
    $('#myPaletteDiv').height($(this).height())
    $('#myDiagramDiv').width($('#myDiagramDiv').width())
    $('#myDiagramDiv').height($(this).height())

    let myDiagram = null;
    let myPalette = null;

    // diagram init
    function init() {
        const $diagram = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates

        myDiagram =
            new go.Diagram("myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
                {
                    grid: $diagram(go.Panel, "Grid",
                        $diagram(go.Shape, "LineH", {stroke: "lightgray", strokeWidth: 0.5}),
                        $diagram(go.Shape, "LineH", {stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 0.5, interval: 10}),
                        $diagram(go.Shape, "LineV", {stroke: "lightgray", strokeWidth: 0.5}),
                        $diagram(go.Shape, "LineV", {stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 0.5, interval: 10})
                    ),
                    "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
                    layout:
                        $diagram(go.TreeLayout,
                            {angle: 90, arrangement: go.TreeLayout.ArrangementFixedRoots}),

                }
            )
        ;

        // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", e => {
            const title = window.title;
            const idx = title.text().indexOf("*");
            if (myDiagram.isModified) {
                if (idx < 0) title.text(title.text() + "*");
                console.log("save")
            } else {
                if (idx >= 0) title.text(title.text().slice(0, idx));
            }
        });

        myDiagram.addModelChangedListener(evt => {
            // ignore unimportant Transaction events
            if (!evt.isTransactionFinished) return;
            var txn = evt.object;  // a Transaction
            if (txn === null) return;
            // iterate over all of the actual ChangedEvents of the Transaction
            txn.changes.each(e => {
                // ignore any kind of change other than adding/removing a node
                // if (e.modelChange !== "nodeDataArray") return;
                if (e.modelChange === "nodeDataArray") {
                    // record node insertions and removals
                    if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Insert) {
                        console.log(evt.propertyName + " added node with key: " + e.newValue.key);
                       
                    } else if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove) {
                        console.log(evt.propertyName + " removed node with key: " + e.oldValue.key);
                    }
                }
                if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Property) {
                    if (e.modelChange === "linkFromKey") {
                        console.log(evt.propertyName + " changed From key of link: " +
                            e.object + " from: " + e.oldValue + " to: " + e.newValue);
                    } else if (e.modelChange === "linkToKey") {
                        console.log(evt.propertyName + " changed To key of link: " +
                            e.object + " from: " + e.oldValue + " to: " + e.newValue);
                    } else if (e.propertyName === "text") {
                        console.log(evt.propertyName + " changed property name: " + e.newValue);
                        
                    }
                } else if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Insert && e.modelChange === "linkDataArray") {
                    console.log(evt.propertyName + " added link: " + e.newValue);
                    
                } else if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove && e.modelChange === "linkDataArray") {
                    console.log(evt.propertyName + " removed link: " + e.oldValue);
                }
            });
        });

        // this simple template does not have any buttons to permit adding or
        // removing properties or methods, but it could!
        myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
            $diagram(go.Node, "Vertical",
                {
                    defaultStretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
                    fromLinkable: true,
                    toLinkable: true,
                },
                $diagram(go.Panel, "Auto", {fromLinkable: false, toLinkable: false},
                    $diagram(go.Shape, "RoundedTopRectangle",
                        {fill: "white"},
                        new go.Binding("_symbolId", "symboldId").makeTwoWay()),
                    $diagram(go.TextBlock,
                        {margin: new go.Margin(2, 2, 0, 2), textAlign: "center"},
                        new go.Binding("text", "header").makeTwoWay()),
                    makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
                ),
                $diagram(go.Panel, "Auto",
                    {minSize: new go.Size(NaN, 70), fromLinkable: false, toLinkable: false},
                    $diagram(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {fill: "white"}),
                    $diagram(go.TextBlock,
                        {width: 120},
                        {margin: new go.Margin(2, 2, 0, 2), textAlign: "center", editable: false},
                        new go.Binding("text", "text").makeTwoWay()),
                    makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
                    makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
                ),
                $diagram(go.Panel, "Auto", {fromLinkable: false, toLinkable: false},
                    $diagram(go.Shape, "RoundedBottomRectangle",
                        {fill: "white"},
                        new go.Binding("fill", "role", r => r[0] === 'b' ? "lightgray" : "white")),
                    $diagram(go.TextBlock,
                        {margin: new go.Margin(2, 2, 0, 2), textAlign: "center"},
                        new go.Binding("text", "footer").makeTwoWay()),
                    makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false),
                ),
                { // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
                    mouseEnter: (e, node) => showSmallPorts(node, true),
                    mouseLeave: (e, node) => showSmallPorts(node, false)
                },
                {
                    contextMenu:     // define a context menu for each node
                        $diagram("ContextMenu",  // that has one button
                            $diagram("ContextMenuButton",
                                $diagram(go.TextBlock, "打开面板"),
                                {click: contextMenuClick})
                            // more ContextMenuButtons would go here
                        )  // end Adornment
                }
            );

        // 工具箱
        myPalette =
            $diagram(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
                {
                    // Instead of the default animation, use a custom fade-down
                    "contextMenuTool.isEnabled": false,
                    "animationManager.initialAnimationStyle": go.AnimationManager.None,
                    "InitialAnimationStarting": animateFadeDown, // Instead, animate with this function
                    nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap,  // share the templates used by myDiagram
                    // model: ),
                    initialScale: .7
                });


        const linkSelectionAdornmentTemplate =
            $diagram(go.Adornment, "Link",
                $diagram(go.Shape,
                    // isPanelMain declares that this Shape shares the Link.geometry
                    {isPanelMain: true, fill: null, stroke: "deepskyblue", strokeWidth: 0})  // use selection object's strokeWidth
            );

        myDiagram.linkTemplate =
            $diagram(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
                {selectable: true, selectionAdornmentTemplate: linkSelectionAdornmentTemplate},
                {relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true, reshapable: true},
                {
                    routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
                    curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
                    corner: 5,
                    toShortLength: 4
                },
                new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
                $diagram(go.Shape,  // the link path shape
                    {isPanelMain: true, strokeWidth: 2}),
                $diagram(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
                    {toArrow: "Standard", stroke: null}),
                $diagram(go.Panel, "Auto",
                    new go.Binding("visible", "isSelected").ofObject(),
                    $diagram(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",  // the link shape
                        {fill: "#F8F8F8", stroke: null}),
                    $diagram(go.TextBlock,
                        {
                            textAlign: "center",
                            font: "10pt helvetica, arial, sans-serif",
                            stroke: "#919191",
                            margin: 2,
                            minSize: new go.Size(10, NaN),
                            editable: true
                        },
                        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
                )
            );


        function contextMenuClick(e, obj) {
            myDiagram.commit(function (d) {
                // get the context menu that holds the button that was clicked
                const contextmenu = obj.part;
                // get the node data to which the Node is data bound
                const nodedata = contextmenu.data;
                // compute the next color for the node
                console.log(contextmenu);
                console.log(nodedata);

                openNodePropPanel(nodedata);
            }, "Open modelDialog");

        }

        // 当鼠标移动到节点时显示/隐藏锚点
        function showSmallPorts(node, show) {
            node.ports.each(function (port) {
                port.fill = show ? "rgba(255,0,0,.5)" : null;
            });
        }

        function makePort(name, spot, output, input) {
            // the port is basically just a small transparent square
            return $diagram(go.Shape, "Circle",
                {
                    fill: null,  // not seen, by default; set to a translucent gray by showSmallPorts, defined below
                    stroke: null,
                    desiredSize: new go.Size(7, 7),
                    alignment: spot,  // align the port on the main Shape
                    alignmentFocus: spot,  // just inside the Shape
                    portId: name,  // declare this object to be a "port"
                    fromSpot: spot, toSpot: spot,  // declare where links may connect at this port
                    fromLinkable: output, toLinkable: input,  // declare whether the user may draw links to/from here
                    fromLinkableDuplicates: false, toLinkableDuplicates: false,
                    fromMaxLinks: 1, toMaxLinks: 1,
                    cursor: "pointer"  // show a different cursor to indicate potential link point
                });
        }

        function animateFadeDown(e) {
            var diagram = e.diagram;
            var animation = new go.Animation();
            animation.isViewportUnconstrained = true; // So Diagram positioning rules let the animation start off-screen
            animation.easing = go.Animation.EaseOutExpo;
            animation.duration = 900;
            // Fade "down", in other words, fade in from above
            animation.add(diagram, 'position', diagram.position.copy().offset(0, 200), diagram.position);
            animation.add(diagram, 'opacity', 0, 1);
            animation.start();
        }

        load();
    } // end init

    function load() {

    }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```